# Why does my container lose its content after a setInterval div replacement in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, internet-explorer

I have been developing a web page using chrome and ff. I recently was told it has to work in IE as well. I have already solved the IE double padding issue. The problem is the content of my "grid" disappears after the javascript setinterval causes the div to be replaced. This only happens when viewing the page in IE.

Here is the code for the page leading up to where it is dynamically created and printed out

```
    <div  id=\"col1a\" style=\"float:left; width:605px; height:300px;\"> \
            <div id=\"GridContent\" class=\"FormContent\"> \
                <div id=\"ContentPlaceHolder1_FormSection\" class=\"FormSection\"> \
                    <div id=\"ContentPlaceHolder1_ProgramGridHeader\" class=\"ProgramGridHeader\"> \
                        <div id=\"ContentPlaceHolder1_HeaderRow\" class=\"HeaderRow\"> \
                            <div readonly=\"readonly\" class=\"Cell\" style=\"width: 57px\">Stage</div><div class=\"Cell\" style=\"width: 78px\">Type</div><div class=\"Cell\" style=\"width: 50px\">Time</div><div class=\"Cell\" style=\"width: 44px\">Int</div><div class=\"Cell\" style=\"width: 44px\">Dry</div><div class=\"Cell\" style=\"width: 44px\">Wet</div><div class=\"Cell\" style=\"width: 52px\">RH%</div><div class=\"Cell\" style=\"width: 72px\">Option</div><div class=\"Cell\" style=\"width: 72px\">Damper</div><div class=\"Cell\" style=\"width: 44px\">Fan</div> \
                        </div><br /> \
                        <div class=\"Row\" position: relative;> \
                                 "};
```

Following is my CSS for IE only

```
.Row { border: solid 0px green; float: left; min-width: 0; clear:both; position: relative; -webkit-border; padding 1;}
.RowCompleted { border: solid 0px #7F9DB9; background-color: #C0C0C0; color: #000;}
.RowNoShower { border: solid 0px #7F9DB9; background-color: #FFF; color: #000;  min-width: 0; }
.RowColdShower { border: solid 1px #7F9DB9; background-color: #ADD8E6; color: #000; }
.RowWarmShower { border: solid 1px #7F9DB9; background-color: #FB0; color: #000; }
.RowHotShower { border: solid 1px #7F9DB9; background-color: #F00; color: #FFF; }
.RowInProgress { border: solid 0px #7F9DB9; background-color: #0F0; color: #000;}
.RowPaused { border: solid 0px #7F0DB9; background-color: #00F; color: #FFF;}
```

I would greatly appreciate help understanding why the content disappears
--Thanks--

Comment: I would recommend placing this code in jsfiddle.net and we can view this better.  The HTML has a lot of escapes and its not quite sure what is actually generated.

Comment: I would also recommend that you learn a simple mantra: Use the right tool for the job. If you have tabular data, use a table, and cut down on all that extra markup.

Comment: @xivo the escapes so many escapes because this is a server response with live data, which has to be written in a way that my embedded web server can understand. In this case it is c inside of an sprintf() statement. Everything above plus the need for contextual hilighting make using a table quite difficult.

Comment: @user1753671 I understand it is generated, but that isn't the resulting code is it?  The question you have given us is a bit halved.  We cannot see the disappearing content.  Is there some type of rendered html that you can show us?  Every browser should be able to show it.  You can show us what it is suppose to show and what it isn't showing in IE.  It is a bit confusing and difficult to properly address your issue with your current question.

Answer (score 0):

Certain versions of IE will only populate an element if the HTML is valid.

I would assume there is a tag that is not closed or an extra quote.

Can you show all the HTML you are trying to replace it with?

Source: http://www.dottodotnet.com/2010/03/jquery-html-problems-in-internet.html

Comment: the html that I'm trying to replace it with is created dynamically, so I never have an idea of what the content is actually going to be all i do is fill in this format

'code' 
"<input readonly=\"readonly\" name=\"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl25\" type=\"text\" value=\"%s\" class=\"%s\" style=\"width:70px;\"/>"

the %s is decides what the server is printing to that section

Comment: You should be able to inspect the actual response in the developer tools for the browser you are using.  Here is some documentation on Chrome's developer tool: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview?hl=fr

Comment: I have been using the chrome development tools along the way I recently discovered that IE does not like something about what the server is posting back. I'm getting information back from the server and it looks correct, but i keep getting a box character and a bunch of extra tabs between the lines of code.

Comment: That sounds like it is not correctly converting line breaks.  You might want to try run something like this on the response: http://www.textfixer.com/tutorials/javascript-line-breaks.php